# Angular scope.$watch not working in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular directive with a `scope.$watch` which is not working, but I know the value is changing.  Here's the directive:

```
   var StepFormDirective = function ($timeout, $sce, dataFactory) {
        return {
            replace: false,
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {
                currentStep: "=",
                title: "="
            },
            template: '<h3>{{title}}</h3><form class="step-form"></form>',
            compile: function (tElem, attrs) {
                return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    scope
                            .$watch(
                                    function(){return scope.currentStep;},
                                    function (newValue) {
                                        var stepFormFields = Array();
                                        stepFormFields.push($sce.trustAsHtml("<p>Fields</p>"));
                                        alert(scope.currentStep);
                                    }
                            );
                };
            }
        };
    };
```

Here's the tag:

`<div title="'test'" currentStep="currentContext.currentStep"></div>`

I know the `currentContext.currentStep` is changing, because I also have this on my page and it updates:

`<pre>{{currentContext.currentStep | json}}</pre>`

The alert gets called the first time, but then when the value changes (evidenced by the bit in the `pre` tags) the alert does not get called again and I have no js console errors.

The output for the step (it's data type) is:

```
{
  "identifier": "830abacc-5f88-4f9a-a368-d8184adae70d",
  "name": "Test 1",
  "action": {
    "name": "Approval",
    "description": "Approve",
    "instructions": "Select 'Approved' or 'Denied'",
    "validOutcomes": [
      {
        "outcome": "Approved",
        "display": "Approved",
        "id": "Approved"
      },
      {
        "outcome": "Denied",
        "display": "Denied",
        "id": "Denied"
      }
    ]
  ...
```

Comment: are you watching object or primitive?

Comment: What do you mean?  The code is there?

Comment: huh? We have no idea what the type of currentStep is. Your code doesn't show that

Comment: My bad, didn't understand the question.  See the edit

Comment: `$watch` without third argument won't watch a big object. The first alert goes off when it is no longer undefined. read the docs for various watch types. Are you sure you need to watch the whole object?

Comment: If possible try watching a single value within `currentStep` ('identifier' seems a likely candidate) -- that'd be a heck of a lot more performant than a deep watch of the whole object.

Comment: A good resource for understand `$watch` depths -- [AngularJS Developer Guide -- Scope Watch Depths](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-watch-depths)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$watch` method with third argument set by true (`objectEquality`):

```
$watch('currentStep', function(newValue){...}, true);
```

Or use `$watchCollection`:

```
$watchCollection('currentStep', function(newValue){...})
```